# function to sort a list of positive numbers to return odd numbers first and even numbers last

Tags: python, python-unittest

i want to write a function that takes in a list of numbers (positive integers) and returns a list of sorted numbers such that odd numbers come first and even numbers come last

For example:

my_sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

my_sort([1, 2]) => [1, 2]

my_sort([2, 1]) => [1, 2]

my_sort([3, 3, 4]) => [3, 3, 4]

my_sort([90, 45, 66]) => [45, 66, 90]'''

This is my code

```
def my_sort(numbers):
    a = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 != 0]
    b = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0]
    new_num = b + a
    for m in numbers:
        if a and b:
            return new_num
        else:
            return "Invalid sorted output"
```

Which fails all the test. I'm new to programming and python. So I'ld appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

And here is the unittest

```
import unittest

class MySortTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.result1 = my_sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
        self.result2 = my_sort([1, 2])
        self.result3 = my_sort([2, 1])
        self.result4 = my_sort([3, 3, 4])
        self.result5 = my_sort([90, 45, 66])

    def test_output_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.result1,  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
        msg='Invalid sorted output')

    def test_output_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.result2,  [1, 2], msg='Invalid sorted    
        output')

    def test_output_3(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.result3,  [1, 2], msg='Invalid sorted  
        output')

    def test_output_4(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.result4,  [3, 3, 4], msg='Invalid sorted
        output')

    def test_output_5(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.result5,  [45, 66, 90], msg='Invalid
        sorted output')
```

Comment: What is the logic of your code? Why do you think it should come close to doing the job?

Comment: What's wrong with using the `key` argument?

Comment: *How* does it fail all the tests?  What result did you get from each call to your sort function?  We need you to fully describe the problem.

Comment: What gave you the idea that your `for` loop or any of the code in it would be useful for solving your problem? Why would you loop over `numbers`? Why would you ever return a string `"Invalid sorted output"` instead of `new_num`? Why are you doing any of that instead of just returning `new_num` immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could so it by splitting the list into odd and even and then sorting both and concatenating the two lists.

```
def my_sort(numbers):
    odd  = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 != 0]
    even = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0]
    return sorted(odd) + sorted(even)
```

See that this

```
>>> my_sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

But using a key function avoids constructing the split lists:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> numbers.sort(key=lambda v: (v%2==0, v))
>>> numbers
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

This sorts the list using a key function that returns a tuple of (0, v) if v is odd and (1, v) if even. This causes the odd numbers to appear before the even numbers in an ascending ordered sort.

It can be turned into a function:

```
def my_sort(numbers):
    return sorted(numbers, key=lambda v: (v%2==0, v))
```

Comment: Thanks. All I had to do was return sorted (odd) and sorted(even)

Answer (score 0):

So, I went ahead and grabbed your code and did just a few tests by myself to see the actual output. Your code doesn't actually sort the list currently. It only puts the even numbers first and the odd numbers second. Which by the sound of it isn't what you want either.

```
>>> my_sort([4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 6, 3])
[4, 2, 6, 5, 7, 1, 3]
>>> my_sort([1, 2])
[2, 1]
```

These were the outputs I got by running your code using the Python interpreter. As you can see the even numbers are first, unsorted, followed by the odd numbers, also unsorted. This just has to do with the way you made the `new_num` list. You have `new_num = b + a`, but you created `b` by looking for all the even numbers `b = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0]` and created `a` by looking for all the odd numbers `a = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 != 0]`. The `%` returns the remainder. So, if a number is divisible by 2 it returns 0 and this means that it is even. So, you can either flip the assignment of `a` and `b` or you can flip when you add them together so `a` is first and `b` is second.

As for the individual chunks not being sorted. Python has a built in sorted function that you can call on list `sorted(my_list)` that returns a sorted version of that list. So, if you just run that on your `a` and `b` when you're adding them together to create your `new_num` list then the numbers for each should be sorted just fine.

Your if statements at the end inside your for loop are also not working properly. Giving an already sorted list just returns the list given. Your code here:

```
for m in numbers:
    if a and b:
        return new_num
    else:
        return "Invalid sorted output"
```

This is looping through the original list given and returns the `new_num` if `a` and `b` exists. Since `a` and `b` will always exist this will always return `new_num` and never the `"Invalid sorted output"` statement. You need to make sure you're checking to see if the `numbers` list is already sorted with the expected output of your function. My suggestion would be check to see if `new_num` is the same as `numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sorted` twice.  First to sort the list, and again to sort it by odd then even using the `key` parameter.

```
x = [3,5,4,1,6,8,10,2,9,7]

sorted(sorted(x), key=lambda x: (x+1)%2)
# returns:
# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work... It makes sense if you are joining Andela.

```
def my_sort(theNumbers):
#pass
evenNumbers=[]
oddNumbers=[]

#CHECK IF EVEN OR ODD THEN STORE THEN SEPARATE
for i in theNumbers:
    if i%2==0:
        evenNumbers.append(i)
    else:
        oddNumbers.append(i)
#print (evenNumbers)

#SORT DEM LISTS
evenNumbers.sort()
oddNumbers.sort()
#print (evenNumbers)

#join the two
oddNumbers+=evenNumbers
print (oddNumbers)


#my_sort([11111, 1, 11, 979749, 1111, 1111])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will sort even and odd numbers without creating a temporary list.

```
def segregateEvenOdd(arr, index=0, iterations=0):
    if iterations == len(arr):
        return arr
    if arr[index]%2 == 0:
        arr.append(arr[index])
        arr.pop(index)
        return segregateEvenOdd(arr, index, iterations+1 )        
    if arr[index]%2 != 0:
        return segregateEvenOdd(arr,index+1,iterations+1)

arr = [ 2, 3, 9, 45, 2, 5, 10, 47 ]
output = segregateEvenOdd(arr)
print(output)
# Output
# [3, 9, 45, 5, 47, 2, 2, 10]
```

Answer (score -1):

This code should work:

```
def sort_integers(list_of_integers):     
        odd_numbers = [n for n in list_of_integers if n%2!=0]
        odd_numbers = sorted(odd_numbers, reverse = True)
        print(odd_numbers)

        even_numbers = [x for x in list_of_integers if x%2 == 0]
        even_numbers = sorted(even_numbers, reverse = True)

        print(even_numbers)

        new_sorted_list  = even_numbers + odd_numbers
        print(new_sorted_list)
```